# CodeIgniter create a layout/template library

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, layout

Before I begin I have to say that I have recently started learning CodeIgniter, so I'm sorry if I repeat this subject once again.

In procedural php I would do something like this

```
// the header.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta name="description" content="blah blah">
      <title>My Site</title>
      <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<php? if($current_page == 'about.php'): ?>
      <link href="css/secondary.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> // or some embed styles (<stlye> ... </style>)
   <?php endif; ?> 


      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="js/main_script.js"></script>

      <php? if($current_page == 'contact.php'): ?>
      <script src="js/validation.js"></script>
      <?php endif; ?>
</head>
<body>
     // end of header.php

     include('template/header.php');

     <h1>Heading1</h1>    
     <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>

     include('template/footer.php');

    //footer.php
    //maybe some js and here
</body>
</html>
```

So I would like to do something similar and in CI. All pages/views will have the same main styles or scripts, but in some cases, some specific pages (like contact.php) may include, and **only** in these pages, some specific styles or scripts (like the validation.js).

I have found this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3tA5AVB454) that shows how to create a template/layout library using CI, but I'm not quite sure how I can apply this functionality to work properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the bottom class in libraries/Layout.php (your app not the sys). In the autoload add the library:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('layout');
```

In your controller just write `$this->layout->render();`

The class will render the layout `views/layouts/default.php` and the view `views/$controller.views/$method.php`

In the default layout just put

```
<?php $this->load->view($view,$data); ?>
```

and thats it.

The code is

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Layout
{
    public $data = array();
    public $view = null;
    public $viewFolder = null;
    public $layoutsFodler = 'layouts';
    public $layout = 'default';
    var $obj;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->obj =& get_instance();
    }

    function setLayout($layout)
    {
        $this->layout = $layout;
    }
    function setLayoutFolder($layoutFolder)
    {
        $this->layoutsFodler = $layoutFolder;
    }

    function render()
    {

        $controller = $this->obj->router->fetch_class();
        $method = $this->obj->router->fetch_method();
        $viewFolder = !($this->viewFolder) ? $controller.'.views' : $this->viewFolder . '.views';
        $view = !($this->view) ? $method : $this->view;

        $loadedData = array();
        $loadedData['view'] = $viewFolder.'/'.$view;
        $loadedData['data'] = $this->data;

        $layoutPath = '/'.$this->layoutsFodler.'/'.$this->layout;
        $this->obj->load->view($layoutPath, $loadedData);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I have developed a library quite similar to yours. Anyway thanks for your reply!

Comment: Thank you, that's great stuff! But can it be that the $data variable in the Controller will not be passed to the view this way? I pass the $data to the render method and changed  $loadedData['data'] = $data;

Comment: example to use
 public function index()
 {
  $this->load->view('layouts/default',  ['view'=>'dashboard/index' , 'data' => []]);
 }

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing layout thing is like bellow.

I get content to data['content'] variable.

**This is my controller.**

```
    class Article extends MY_Controller {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('article_model');
        }

        public function index() {

            $data['allArticles']    =   $this->article_model->getAll(); 

            $data['content']        =   $this->load->view('article', $data, true);
            $this->load->view('layout', $data);

        }
```

This is my Layout.I'm using bootstrap layout.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="author" content="">
            <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>
            <base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />

            <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
            <link href="assets/bootstrap3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
            <!--    <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

            <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

            <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
        </head>

        <body>

            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Article Management System</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Admin <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="article/add">Add Article</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="article">All Article</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container" style="margin-top: 80px;">

                <?php echo $content; ?>

            </div><!-- /.container -->


            <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
            ================================================== -->
            <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/bootstrap3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**This is my content view**

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

            <div class="page-header">
                <h4>All Articles </h4>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($allArticles as $row) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row->title; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo substr($row->description,0,100); ?> ....</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the same thing with the following:

Put this code in your `./application/core/MY_Controller.php` file:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
    {
        protected $layout = 'layout/main';

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        protected function render($file = NULL, &$viewData = array(), $layoutData = array())
        {
            if( !is_null($file) ) {
                $data['content'] = $this->load->view($file, $viewData, TRUE);
                $data['layout'] = $layoutData;
                $this->load->view($this->layout, $data);
            } else {
                $this->load->view($this->layout, $viewData);
            }

            $viewData = array();
        }
   }
```

Create a layout folder inside `./application/views` directory and then create your files with the entire html in it. Just put the `<?php echo $content; ?>` in that file where you want to put the dynamic content in it. Then in your controllers use `$this->render();` and pass your file path and data. If you want to use a different layout for specific page just put the `$this->layout = 'path_to_your_layout_file';` it will override the layout file to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with a similar problem not long ago. My solution to it was the following :
In your controller constructor create 2 arrays one of css files and one of js files and put in them the files common to all views. 
And in each function in the controller add to them logic specific files. 
For your example you'll have something like this :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->page_data = array();
        $this->page_data['css']=array('main.css','bootstrap.css');
        $this->page_data['js']=array('main.js','bootstrap.js');
    }
    public function about()
    {
       array_push($this->page_data['css'],'secondary.css');
       $this->load->view('main_layout',$this->page_data)
    }
    public function contact()
    {}


 }
```

And in your view file you'll just iterate over the $css and $js array and include them one by one.
You can extend that easily to include header and footer templates by pushing them into the page_data array.

I ended up switching to doing all the templating on the client-side with Backbone and using Code Igniter as a REST API only but this technique gave me relatively clean code for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I use this, in older version of CodeIgniter and it works for version 3 as well.

```
<?php  
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Layout
{

    var $obj;
    var $layout;

    function Layout($layout = "layout_main")
    {
        $this->obj =& get_instance();
        $this->layout = $layout;
    }

    function setLayout($layout)
    {
      $this->layout = $layout;
    }

    function view($view, $data=null, $return=false)
    {
        $loadedData = array();
        $loadedData['content_for_layout'] = $this->obj->load->view($view,$data,true);

        if($return)
        {
            $output = $this->obj->load->view($this->layout, $loadedData, true);
            return $output;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->obj->load->view($this->layout, $loadedData, false);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and to call this in the controller I use:

```
$this->layout->view('apps/apps', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

5 Simple Steps to create CodeIgniter Template:

## Step #1

Template.php @ libraries

## Step #2

Write following code

```
/* Start of file Template.php */
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Template {
        var $template_data = array();
        function set($name, $value)
        {
            $this->template_data[$name] = $value;
        }
        function load($template = '', $view = '' , $view_data = array(), $return = FALSE)
        {               
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
            $this->set('contents', $this->CI->load->view($view, $view_data, TRUE));         
            return $this->CI->load->view($template, $this->template_data, $return);
        }
}
/* End of file Template.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/libraries/Template.php */
```

## Step #3

open config/autoload.php
at line 55 replace

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session','encrypt');
with this code
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session','encrypt', 'template');
```

## Step #4

On my controller call template as

```
//start
$this->template->load(TEMPLATE_NAME, VIEW_NAME , $this->data);
//end
```

## Step #5

On views
create a file as custom_template.php
And place there following code--

```
//start
<?php $this->load->view('elements/header'); ?>
<div><?php echo $contents;?></div>
<?php $this->load->view('elements/footer'); ?>
//end
```

*N.B.* In views in elements folder create two files as **header.php** And **footer.php**

Comment: So does it means <body> tag on header.php, and the close tag </body> on footer.php? If yes, this is very bad pattern.